# Wordpress Permalinks not working - Apache Configuration Reset

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

On Live server, to resolve 404 error when trying to access any page, changed below setting in `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But on next day it gets reset to below

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Really hoping that it was going to work, but no go. This is what `.htaccess` looked like after I changed the permalink option:

```
<Directory />
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The pages are still not accessible. Changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` works, but it resets again to default setting somehow.

404 page not found error appears often even after changing `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`.

Note: `mod_rewrite` is already installed

Comment: Did you install "mod_rewrite" in your apache ?

Comment: @Germanaz0, `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is mentioned in my `httpd.conf`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy what do you mean by `but it resets again to default setting somehow.` Once you change it, it won't change back by itself.

Comment: @PanamaJack, that is whats happening, I have changed `AllowOverride None` from WHM panel, but it again resets to `AllowOverride None` on next day, making all pages non-accessible (404)